# Is it possible to work with an connection range BLE?

Tags: connection, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

For one of our projects i'm looking for a way to only let centrals (native iOS or Android app) connect with the perhiperal when they are inside a defined connection range (distance around the perhiperal).

I know that BLE is not designed for distance measuring but i hoped there is a **reliable** way to make a difference between centrals in a range <2m from the perhiperal and centrals >3,5 meter from the perhiperal.This means i do not need to measure the exact distance.

An important thing to mentoin is that our perhiperal can be located in an "open field" situation but also in situations where it is surounded with walls or concrete for example in a entry floor of a building or a carpark.

Another possible issue is that the central can be inside a car but if this is the case, all centrals for the concerning perhiperal are inside a car. Ofcourse it can be different cars.

Note that there is max 1 perhiperal at the time inside the connection range.

In our current version we developed an formulla what uses the received RSSI strength to estimate the distance. Unfortunately we cannot get this working reliable enough. Maybe we need to use another formulla or calibration method or whatever, we really tried many things during the last 6 months.

The concrete question is:
Is it technically possible to achieve the target as described above and when yes, what is the way to achieve the target above? We are open for specific BLE antenna's or specific designed casings for the BLE antenna or whatever is needed. It is also okay when we need to build an calibration application or specific hardware to calibrate our perhiperals, for each perhiperal, so we are realy open minded for any solution as long as it works reliable!

When more info is required to give an answere, please let me know what is missing and i will complete the info.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, it is like you said, you cannot use Bluetooth or Bluetooth Low Energy for short distance/range measurements. Bluetooth was just not designed that way. You want to get accurate reliable measurement for something between 2-3.5, this is way too small for BLE to be capable of that. I know that this is not what you want to hear, but I have already tried this and wasted many months on this before.

The only thing I can recommend if you really really need to continue down this path is that in order to get a more reliable outcome, you will need many many devices that are measuring the RSSI simultaneously, and then those devices need to be talking to each other to get an average RSSI measurement. You may also want to look at configuring the Tx power based on the average readings that you get, i.e. the closer the device gets, you lower the Tx power of both the scanning and advertising devices. Finally, directional antennas can be used if you are planning to use non-Android non-iOS devices for scanning, but this will be tricky if the only antenna you can change is that of the peripheral.

Comment: Thanks for your response, do you know if we can achieve our targets by using WiFi ? as someone told me the distance can be measured more accurate with WiFi... But i have no idea if and how to use WiFi for this...